# How to context of a sequence in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

Given a text such as

> The green ball  on the table is mine

I want to extract the contexts of size 2 (to the right and left) of any sequence in the sentence above.

For example, given the sequence **green ball**, i expect to have **"The", "on","the,"table"** as the contexts.

Also given **The**, I want to have **"green", "ball" "on", "the"** as the contexts. Given given **mine**, I want to have **"on", "the" "table", "is"** as the contexts.

Since **The** does not have contexts on the left. it picks the 4 contexts from the right, the same applies to  **mine**.

I tried out something but my method was based on splitting as shown below

```
query = "green ball"
context_window=2
texts="The green ball  on the table is mine"

tokens = texts.split()
index = tokens.index(query)
begin = max(0, index - context_window)
end = min(index + 1 + context_window, len(tokens))
context_words = tokens[begin:end]
```

I discovered it cannot work in this case. Any way out?

Comment: green and ball will be 2 separate items in the list. Trying to find the index of "green ball" will raise an error because that item isn't in the list.

Comment: So green ball has the context of 1 to the left and 3 to the right? i.e. The on the table?

Comment: Just to be sure: your issue is only in the case when `query` contains a space, right? A quick and dirty solution would be to substitute `query` for a `'magic_cookie'`, use your code, and substitute it back in the answer. Although a regexp solution would be nicer...

Comment: what should happen if the key is repeated, e.g. looking for the contexts of `is` in "the green ball is on the table and it is mine"

Comment: @Pynchia I am not expecting such case to exist often in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input string into 2 parts: the part to the left of the query and the part to the right of it.

Then split the left and right parts into words. Get the last `context_window` words of the left part and the first `context_window` words of the right part. If either part is shorter than `context_window`, add the difference to the number of words you get from the other part.

Finally, get the last words from the left part and the first words from the right part.

```
query = "green ball"
context_window=2
texts="The green ball  on the table is mine"
left = texts[0:texts.find(query)]
right = texts[texts.find(query)+len(query):]

if left:
    left_tokens = left.split()
else:
    left_tokens = []

if right:
    right_tokens = right.split()
else:
    right_tokens = []

if len(left_tokens) >= context_window and len(right_tokens) >= context_window:
    left_context = context_window
    right_context = context_window
elif len(left_tokens) < context_window:
    left_context = len(left_tokens)
    right_context = context_window + (context_window - left_context)
else:
    right_context = len(right_tokens)
    left_context = context_window + (context_window - right_context)

context_words = left_tokens[-left_context:] + right_tokens[0:right_context]
```